# Is there a common way to permanantly store Jars in jenkins

Tags: jar, jenkins

I have a project with a few important releases. I'd like to flag certain builds as "permanant" in jenkins, so that I can access them forever (i.e. outside of the daily cleared build workspace).

Is there a simple way to do this?

I've seen the jenkins artifactory plugin, but that seems heavy weight.

Comment: Have you considered publishing files to a respository manager like Nexus or Artifactory? That would be the normal solution to this problem

Comment: Yes but was interested in something lighter weight .. basically, i want jenkins to keep jars from each commit which accompanied a tag in a permanant public folder.  No need for a manual publishing step.

Comment: I can recommend Nexus as a very lightweight process. The point is while Jenkins can store your artifacts it is primarily designed to build code. Nexus, on the other hand, is designed to as a repository store and integrates very well with Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

I think Jenkins can do that, but it may become cumbersome to maintain.

You can add a post-build step 'archive artifacts' and either
- do not discard old builds at all
- on each build you want to keep - mark it as 'keep this build forever' <- there is this small button in upper right corner of each build page